# Jsoup - Extract surround paragraph for extracted URLS

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For each hyperlink, I have to extract actual hyperlinks, anchor text and the surrounding paragraph for each URL (excluding all tags).

I am able to extract link data using jsoup easily but not able to extract the paragraph that contains the hyperlink. I tried the following things:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

for (Element link : links) {
        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("abs:href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text()); 
        System.out.println("Surr : " + link.select("p").text()); -- not work
       }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in links that are nested in paragraphs you can use this selector:

```
Elements paragraphs = document.select("p:has(a[href])")
```

Then when you will iterate over those paragraph elements, you can extract nested a-elements by:

```
for (Element paragraph : paragraphs) {
    System.out.println(paragraph.select("a[href]"));
}
```

In this case you have an access to the nested a-elements and paragraphs they are surround with.

I've created a simple gist you can download and run easily - https://gist.github.com/wololock/ffd9ef32f7abe3f325b0